# How to host hangout XML file in Server?

Tags: google-hangouts

1.How to host Hangout XML file in Server?

2.If Existing Hangout Application how to edit that file.

3.Please let me know how to create hangout Applications?Please specify the steps.

Comment: Are you able to hangout API configuration at google console?  whenever I try to set public url at api configuration I got error 'The user request is invalid. Please check your URL and try again.'